# Не получилось пройти по списку с библиотекой 'pywhatkit' как послать одно сообщение на 2 номера телефона по Вотсапу?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Работает с одним номером но как только я создаю список номеров пишет:

```
"raise CountryCodeException("Country code missing from phone_no")
pywhatkit.exceptions.CountryCodeException: Country code missing from phone_no".
```

Тут работает на 1 номер...

```
# pip install -U pywhatkit

import pywhatkit

number = "+972548336070"
message = "The Matrix has you..."
hours = 00
minutes = 41


pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(number, message,hours , minutes)
```

вот так не работает по списку из двух номеров...

```
# pip install -U pywhatkit

import pywhatkit

number = ["+972548336070", "+972548336071"]

for i in number:
    message = "The Matrix has you..."
    hours = 00
    minutes = 41
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(number, message,hours , minutes)
```

как скормить список этой библиотеке?
зарание спасибо!

Если есть другое решение как послать одно сообщение на 2 номера телефона по Вотсапу буду рад.

Answer (score 1):

у вас отступ неправильный. Вызов функции надо поместить в цикл. Также замените переменную в вызове функции. Там должно быть `i` а не `number`.

```
import pywhatkit

number = ["+972548336070", "+972548336071"]

for i in number:
    message = "The Matrix has you..."
    hours = 00
    minutes = 41
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(i, message,hours , minutes)
```